# Saving user created elements in android app

Tags: android

In my app, when the user presses the add button icon, a new button is created and a dialog box pops up so the user can name the button. But, when the user closes out the program and reopens it, the layout is obviously reset. How can I save the buttons that were created by the user even after they kill the app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Persistent storage. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Don't store "buttons", though, just the data that was entered, and re-create the buttons when you read the data back out

Comment: use share preference to store data of users   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedpreferences

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
               Button b1;

               public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
               public static final String Name = "nameKey";

               SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

               @Override
               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                  checkIfButtonNameAlreadyPresent();

                  b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                        editor.putString(Name, /* name from the pop up */);
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                  });
               }

        public void checkIfButtonNameAlreadyPresent(){
           sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,              Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String name = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "");
            if (name.equals("")){
            b1.setText("Button");
            } else {
            //this should be executed if any name you added ever
            b1.setText(name)
           }
         }
}
```